# Azure DevOps Project Settings - Teams - Set team as project default. What does a default team do?

Tags: azure, azure-devops

We are using Azure DevOps for development. We have several teams but one team needs to be the "Default" team. Does this affect anything else than that the default team can not be removed? I have not found any documentation what the project default team does.

[image]

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/settings/add-teams?view=azure-devops&tabs=preview-page

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/settings/about-teams-and-settings?view=azure-devops#the-default-team

Answer (score 0):

In the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/settings/about-teams-and-settings?view=azure-devops#the-default-team) you sent:

> Backlogs, boards, and dashboards are automatically configured for this
> default team so that you can start defining work items and your
> backlog.

Comment: True but if you create a new Team you will get a new Dashboard for that team, you can create a sprint for the new team and get a boards etc. If you configure a team area the backlog items can be viewed there. My point is simply that the default team does not seems to have any affect that can't be set somewhere else in the system.

Comment: You're right, you can create teams and dashboards/backlog for them, the only affect of the "Default" team it's for the default backlog/dashboard/board you will see, and not somewhere else in the system. of course you can configure to see another dashboard but without it the default will be of the default team.